# How to jump to the end of a for loop, but not leaving it, with goto

Tags: c++, stdvector, goto

I have a function that finds all multiple elements in a vector. If I send in `{1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,3,7}` it returns `{1,2,3}`.
My input vector has about 100 to 10000 elements but I expect to have only very few different(!) duplicates; around 1-5%.

Hence I check against my duplicates vector if I already identified an element as occurring multiple times. If so, the function shall go on to the next element if there are any. For this I use a `goto`.

But I need to have a command after the `goto label`. Else the compiler complains. Is there any way to avoid the this and keep the goto? I know that I could use some other method, e.g. setting a bool accordingly and using a if(). However I think the goto method is straight forward.

```
vector<int> findDublicates(vector<int> const& v) {
    // e.g. {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,7} -> {1,2,3}
    vector<int> dublicates;
    for (auto it(v.begin()); it != v.end() - 1;
         ++it) { // go through each element except the last
        for (auto const& i :
             dublicates) { // check if this is already a known dublicate
            if (i == *it)
                goto nextElement; // if so, goto the next element in v
        }
        for (auto it2(it + 1); it2 != v.end();
             ++it2) { // else compare it with the "not checked" elements in v
            if (*it == *it2) { // if a dublicate is found, keep it
                dublicates.emplace_back(*it);
                break; // check the next element in v; could also use goto
                       // nextElement
            }
        }
    nextElement:
        cout << " "; // if I remove cout it won't compile: "expected
                     // primary-expression before '}' token"
    }
    return dublicates;
}
```

Comment: The command could simply be a semi-colon.  That is a null statement, but it should satisfy the compiler.

Comment: Looks like using  _good old_ for loops with the traditional condition parts, and `break;` statements would make up cleaner c++ code.

Comment: Note to casual readers: `continue` cannot be used here because the OP needs to skip to the next iteration of an *outer* loop in the nest.

Comment: `v.end() - 1;` causes UB if the vector is empty, it'd be good to check for this first

Comment: Replacing both `for` loops with `std::find` calls will make this problem go away.  (Of course, the algorithm could be improved too)

Comment: @dani, you know this can all be done without hand-coded loops and goto.  One example: http://ideone.com/zWJtMs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use a semicolon as a no-op.

```
    nextElement:
    ;
}
```

However, I'm not sure if your method for finding duplicates is efficient.  You might be better off sorting the array, then iterating it once.  Sorting the vector will group all of the duplicates together.  Then you'll simply have to check if the current element is the same as the previous element.

Comment: thanks. In another version, I use it for finding equal objects for which sorting is somehow difficult but just comparing is not...

Comment: You might consider using a std::set as well, instead of a vector.  Sets are automatically sorted and in this case more efficient as @Mr.Llama suggests.

Answer (score 0):

If removing the `goto` won't kill you, try using a Boolean helper variable:

```
for(auto it(v.begin()); it!=v.end()-1; ++it) { //go through each element except the last
    bool found = false;
    for(auto const &i : dublicates) { //check if this is already a known dublicate
        if(i==*it)
        {
           found = true;
           break;
         }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        for(auto it2(it+1); it2!=v.end(); ++it2) { //else compare it with the "not checked" elements in v
            if(*it==*it2) { //if a dublicate is found, keep it
                dublicates.emplace_back(*it);
                break; //check the next element in v; could also use goto nextElement
            }
        }
     }
    cout<<" "; //if I remove cout it won't compile: "expected primary-expression before '}' token"
}
```

Usage of `goto` is considered bad form in programming.  Search the web for "spaghetti code goto".

Comment: I would consider my version to be much more readable than this.

Comment: The bool found is not better than a goto (having a chain of multiple filters it becomes an annoyance)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend restructuring your code to not use a goto.  Gotos can be useful, but they are frowned upon and can usually be replaced with more readable structure.

Consider:

```
bool isDublicate( int candidate, vector<int> const & dublicates )
{
    for ( auto const &i: dublicates )
        if ( i == candidate ) return true;
    return false;
}

vector<int> findDublicates(vector<int> const &v) {
    //e.g. {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,7} -> {1,2,3}
    vector<int> dublicates;
    for(auto it(v.begin()); it!=v.end()-1; ++it) { //go through each element except the last
        if ( isDublicate( *it, dublicates ) )
            continue;

        for(auto it2(it+1); it2!=v.end(); ++it2) { //else compare it with the "not checked" elements in v
            if(*it==*it2) { //if a dublicate is found, keep it
                dublicates.emplace_back(*it);
                break; //check the next element in v; could also use goto nextElement
            }
        }
    }
    return dublicates;
}
```

Comment: Nice try - but incomplete - you should avoid continue and break

Comment: @DieterLücking: break would take you out of the function prematurely.  Continue pops you to the top of the loop again, just as dani originally intended.